# How to install npm modules using a python script in the directory where my script is located

Tags: python, python-3.x, npm, npm-install

The file structure should look like :

`test.py`

`node_modules`  (The folder containing installed npm modules)

I have tried this :

```
import subprocess
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) #holds the directory where python script is located
directory where python script is located
os.chdir(dir_path)
subprocess.call(["npm","init"])
subprocess.call(["npm","install"])
```

**Error** :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Alifreeze.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.1.58038\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in 
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\Alifreeze.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.1.58038\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd__main__.py", line 432, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Alifreeze.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.1.58038\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd__main__.py", line 316, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='**main**')
  File "C:\Users\Alifreeze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Alifreeze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Alifreeze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Alifreeze\Desktop\ShellScripts\npm.py", line 6, in 
    subprocess.call(["npm","init"])
  File "C:\Users\Alifreeze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 323, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\Alifreeze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in **init**
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Alifreeze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me!

```
import subprocess
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) #holds the directory where python script is located
os.chdir(dir_path)
subprocess.check_call('npm init', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["npm","init"])
subprocess.call(["npm","install"])
```

try this code in the test.py script, package.json should be present in the same folder while running the python script

Comment: what if nothing was there ? how do i run npm init and then npm install ?

Also i want to install say `aws-sdk` how should i do that

Comment: you can add subprocess.call("npm","init")  above the npm install line, this will ask you setup question for node application and you can proceed from there

Comment: Okay let me try this i will verify the answer and upvote it if this works.. cheers :)

Comment: No luck :( its giving an error saying FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Can you share detailed error ? Also I tried this solution with Ubuntu OS, I think you are using Windows OS ?

Comment: I got it working and posted an answer if you want to refer it anyways i will upvote your answers really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Cheers :) Happy Coding